# Android won't connect to WiFi without Internet connection

Tags: wi-fi

The title says it: Android mobile phone won't connect to a WiFi network that doesn't have an Internet connection.

Our clients can't connect to a SoftAP network that our device creates. They see the SoftAP network, try to connect to it and are immediately removed from the network.

When I connect to the same SoftAP network, there is a warning that the said WiFi network doesn't have internet access. I then have to approve being connected to the said network. After I approve it, the application we use works fine.

Our clients are from Austria and we are based in Serbia. Don't know if this has anything to do with it. Also, almost all of our Android test devices are in developer mode. Again, don't know if this has anything to do with it, just trying to give as much info as possible.

Comment: Have you tried giving "real" DNS and a default gateway to the network (but allow no real connections to the outer world, dropping them silently) - I seem to remember, that this tricked earlier Androids into using such a network.

Comment: I'll ask them to try it now. Will post results when they do. Thanks